# Javascript class variables and class methods cannot be referred to inside class

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

This problem has been bugging me sooo badly. I'm sure this question has been answered, but I am at a loss as I've been searching for about half an hour.

Here's my problem:

In Javascript, I have created a class called `Game`.

The class currently looks like this:

```
class Game {
    this.test = "";
    this.number = 0;
    constructor()
    {
        this.cWidth = 480;
        this.cHeight = 360;
        this.i = 0;

    }
    run()
    {

        var human = new User(192,175);
        var bot1 = new Bot(339,92);
        var bot2 = new Bot(352,255);
        setInterval(this.updateGameArea, 1000 / 60);
    }
    updateGameArea()
    {
        this.clear();
        this.update();

    }
    clear()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.cWidth,this.cHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"
        console.log("cleared! cwidth=" + this.cWidth + "; cHeight = " + this.cHeight);
    }
    update()
    {
        var pos = getCoords();
        drawMousePos();
        return;
    }
}

Game game = new game();
game.run();
```

Note that the class is also being run inside of Jquery's `$(document).ready(function(){})`, but should work since other, simpler classes work.

I'm having multiple issues:

1. Variables cannot be defined outside the class. `test` and `number` throw syntax errors, saying `game.js:161 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

According to the [Mozilla class syntax page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), it seems that one is allowed to instantiate variables using the `this` keyword without the constructor.

2. In `updateGameArea()`, `clear()` and `update()` cannot be referenced. However, in `run()`, they can. I have been able to get around this by setting `clear()` and `update()` to static and call them by using `Game.update()` and `Game.clear()`, but I'd prefer if I could do it the right way.
3. The variables `cWidth` and `cHeight` DO NOT hold their values. When I was testing `clear()` when it was static, `cWidth` and `cHeight` were both undefined.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `this.test = "";
    this.number = 0;` needs to be inside the `constructor`. That's not valid JavaScript otherwise. Also `setInterval(this.updateGameArea.bind(this), ...)` or `setInterval(() => this.updateGameArea(), ...)` to preserve calling context.

Comment: `test`, `number`, `cWidth` and `cHeight` aren't "variables", they are instance fields. Variables are declared with `var` and `let`, which give them scope to be available within. `this.Xyz` members are tied to the specific instance of the class and can't work across instances.

Comment: `Game game = new game();` really should be something like `const game = new Game();`

Comment: "*According to the Mozilla class syntax page, it seems that one is allowed to instantiate variables using the this keyword without the constructor*" - no, where are you reading that?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I was mistaken by one of its examples where a variable was instantiated using `this` keyword INSIDE a function inside the class.

Comment: "Variables" are never "instantiated" (they get "initialized" - Objects get instantiated) and if they have `this` in front of them, they are not variables, they are instance fields.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the correction.